# Swift NSCountedSet init with array bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

There seems to be a bug in Swift Playground with the use of NSCountedSet.

This code works as intended

```
let numbers = [1,2,2,4,6,7,8,8,5,8,1]

let set = NSSet(array: numbers)
```

but when I try to create an NSCountedSet in the same fashion

```
var bag = NSCountedSet(array: numbers)
```

I get this error

> Playground execution failed:
>   /var/folders/bl/1tnlvfzd4mqb9gkpx0h8rxy00000gp/T/lldb/6514/playground599.swift:56:31:
>   error: 'Int' is not identical to 'AnyObject' var bag =
>   NSCountedSet(array: numbers)

I did try casting numbers

```
let nums = numbers as [AnyObject]
var bag = NSCountedSet(array: nums)
```

then I get this error

> Playground execution failed:
>   /var/folders/bl/1tnlvfzd4mqb9gkpx0h8rxy00000gp/T/lldb/6514/playground732.swift:58:23:
>   error: extra argument 'array' in call var bag = NSCountedSet(array:
>   nums)

Am I missing something here?

I can work around the problem by doing this

```
var bag = NSCountedSet()
for number in numbers {
    bag.addObject(number)
}
```

But it is not very elegant

Comment: That is indeed strange. `let bag = NSCountedSet(array: [])` and `let bag = NSCountedSet(set: set)` also do not compile. Send a bug report to Apple!

Comment: Sent a bug report. Thanks

Comment: The above code no longer fails in playgrounds in Xcode 6.3 beta 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** As @carbo18 reported, this has been fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta 4.

**Old answer:** That definitely looks like a bug. `NSCountedSet` has initializers

```
convenience init(array: [AnyObject])
convenience init(set: NSSet)
```

but

```
let b1 = NSCountedSet(array: [])     // extra argument 'array' in call
let b2 = NSCountedSet(set: NSSet())  // extra argument 'set' in call
```

both fail to compile.

This was also reported in the Apple Developer Forum (https://devforums.apple.com/message/1081850#1081850),
where the following workaround is given:

```
let numbers = [1,2,2,4,6,7,8,8,5,8,1]
let bag = NSCountedSet()
bag.addObjectsFromArray(numbers)
```

Comment: The above question was a bug with Xcode 6.2 and has been fixed in Xcode 6.3 Beta 4

Comment: weird, still a bug in 6.4 (6E35b)