# Most common dictionary in array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I need to find the most common dictionary in an array of swift dictionaries. I tried using the following :

```
func frequencies
                <S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: Hashable>
                (source: S) -> [(S.Generator.Element,Int)] {

                    var frequency: [S.Generator.Element:Int] = [:]

                    for x in source {
                        frequency[x] = (frequency[x] ?? 0) + 1
                    }

                    return sorted(frequency) { $0.1 > $1.1 }
            }
```

But I can't invoke 'frequencies' with an argument list of type `[[String:String]]()`. How can I edit the above function to take an array of dictionaries, or use another method entirely?

Comment: I think you need to define "common" as applied to a dictionary first. Did you want the most common element across every dictionary?

Comment: Yeah I need to order the most common dictionaries in the array, as well as return their counts. I.e. `[[name: David, number: 1], [name: John, number: 2], [name: David, number: 1]]` should return something like `[[name: David, number: 1], [name: John, number: 2]]` along with counts of each object in that ordered array.

Comment: Notice that your array of `[String: String]` is not `Hashable`. Only the dictionary's keys are hashable. Since there might be more than one key in your dictionary, do you just need the most common `name`s? What if two dictionaries have the same name and different surname?

Comment: If name _and_ surname aren't identical, then they'd be considered different objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/index.html) which provides this kind of functionality:

```
let arr = [
    [
        "foo": "bar"
    ],
    [
        "foo": "bar"
    ],
    [
        "foo": "baz"
    ],
]

let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: arr)
for dict in countedSet {
    println(countedSet.countForObject(dict))
    println(dict)
}
```

prints

> 2
>
> ["foo": "bar"]
>
> 1
>
> ["foo": "baz"]

If you're having problems with the initializer not woking properly, use:

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet()
countedSet.addObjectsFromArray(arr)
```

instead of

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: arr)
```

I haven't tested with Swift 2, but the usage should be more or less the same.

Comment: I'm declaring `var dictArray = [[String:String]]()` but at `let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: dictArray)` I'm getting `Cannot find an initializer` that accepts that type

Comment: yeah it seems there's an issue with `NSCountedSet`'s initializer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172374/swift-nscountedset-init-with-array-bug. If you can't use Swift 2 (I'd guess they resolved the issue since 1.2), try creating an empty `NSCountedSet` and adding the array elements after init.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have mentioned, the problem is that the type `[String:String]` is not `Hashable`.

A (much) less efficient solution when your types are not hashable is to fall back to `Comparable` (could sort and generate running totals) or `Equatable` or, worst case, require the caller to supply a `isEquivalent` closure.  Then you go hunting through your running frequencies searching for an equivalent item (and if you don't find one, insert it with a frequency of 1).

Here is an implementation that does that in Swift 2.0:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func frequencies(@noescape isEquivalent: (Generator.Element,Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> [(Generator.Element,Int)] {
        var frequency: [(Generator.Element,Int)] = []

        for x in self {
            // find the index of the equivalent entry
            if let idx = frequency.indexOf({ isEquivalent($0.0, x)}) {
                // and bump the frequency
                frequency[idx].1 += 1
            }
            else {
                // add a new entry
                frequency.append(x,1)
            }

        }

        return frequency.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    }
}
```

Since there is an implementation of `==` that compares two dictionaries, so long as those dictionaries contain values that are equatable, you can call it like this:

```
let dicts = [
    ["name": "David", "number": "1"],
    ["name": "John", "number": "2"],
    ["name": "David", "number": "1"],
]

// you can use `==` in two dictionaries that contain an equatable value,
// such as String here:
dicts[0] == dicts[1]  // false
dicts[0] == dicts[2]  // true

// so you can call frequencies like so:
dicts.frequencies(==)
```

which returns:

```
[(["number": "1", "name": "David"], 2), 
 (["number": "2", "name": "John"], 1)]
```

---

edit: here is a Swift 1.2 version, unfortunately complicated by the absence of a version of `find` in 1.2 (renamed `indexOf` in 2.0) that takes a predicate.  This ought to work, but I don't have a working copy of 1.2 in this machine so you may need to fix any syntax errors:

```
extension Array {
    // add missing indexOf to Array as 1.2 doesn't have an equivalent
    func indexOf(@noescape predicate: T->Bool) -> Int? {
        for idx in indices(self) {
            if predicate(self[idx]) { return idx }
        }
        return nil
    }

}

func frequencies<S: SequenceType>
    (source: S, @noescape isEquivalent: (S.Generator.Element,S.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> [(S.Generator.Element,Int)] {

        var frequency: [(S.Generator.Element,Int)] = []

        for x in source {
            // find the index of the equivalent entry
            if let idx = frequency.indexOf({ isEquivalent($0.0, x)}) {
                // and bump the frequency
                frequency[idx].1 += 1
            }
            else {
                // add a new entry
                frequency.append(x,1)
            }

        }

        return sorted(frequency) { $0.1 > $1.1 }
}

frequencies(dicts, ==)
```

Comment: It works, only I suppose the question was not intended for Swift 2.0. Anyway `==` works for earlier version...

Comment: Yup would be fairly easy to back port back to a 1.2 free function

Comment: Sure, only I just don't think it would be fair for others to do it :-)

Comment: @MatteoPiombo 1.2 version added (though I don't have a copy right now to test with, so fingers crossed I got it right).

Comment: `frequencies(dicts, ==)`  for Swift 1.2

Comment: @MatteoPiombo thanks, approved your edit - if you've verified it now compiles/works in 1.2 I'll edit out the caveat that it might not...

Comment: Yes it works. Strange I had to use `sorted` since in playground `.sort` complained. I remember `sort` should have worked in 1.2 as well :-/

Answer (score -1):

(I don't know if this works with Swift 1.2)

You can also use a global function:

```
func frequencies<K, V where K : Hashable, V: Equatable>(dicts: [[K : V]]) -> [(dict: [K : V], count: Int)] {
    var counts = [(dict: [K : V], count: Int)]()

    for dict in dicts {
        if let index = counts.indexOf({ $0.dict == dict }) {
            counts[index].1++
        } else {
            counts.append(dict: dict, count: 1)
        }
    }

    return counts.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
}
```

Use like this

```
let dicts = [
    ["name": "David", "number": "1"],
    ["name": "John" , "number": "2"],
    ["name": "David", "number": "1"],
]

print(frequencies(dicts))
```

outputs

```
[(["number": "1", "name": "David"], 2), 
 (["number": "2", "name": "John" ], 1)]
```

Comment: Please provide some feedback when downvoting